# Group 2 array on an array python 3 (array in array)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I need to group 2 array, it takes from different data. and I want to group them to an array.

For example I have

```
arrTrain[index][5] = [29.8496231131986], [23.748684174075834]
```

and

```
arrTrain[index][4] = [1],[0]
```

So I need to group them to =

```
[[[29.8496231131986],[1]],[[23.748684174075834],[0]]]
```

my program

```
tabel = []
for i in range(0,1):
   temp = []
   for j in range(0,2):
       euc = [math.sqrt(((arrTrain[j][0] - arrTes[i][0])**2) + ((arrTrain[j][1]-arrTes[i][1])**2) + ((arrTrain[j][2] - arrTes[i][2])**2) + ((arrTrain[j][3]-arrTes[i][3])**2))]
      hoaxbaru = [arrTrain[j][4]]
      temp.append(euc)
      temp.append(hoaxbaru)
      tabel.append(temp)
print(table)
```

and the output is

```
[[[29.8496231131986], [0], [23.748684174075834], [0]], [[29.8496231131986], [0], [23.748684174075834], [0]]]
```

Comment: I suppose the last "table" is a typo

Answer (score 0):

To merge arrays in such way you could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function.

example:

```
>>> arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> arr2 = [7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> zipped = zip(arr1,arr2)
>>> list(zipped)
[(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10), (5, 11), (6, 12)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize temp as empty list inside the **inner** loop.

```
temp=[]
```

Else it just keeps appending to previous data.